# Why seem my program memory write faster than read?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, memory

My simple program:

```
//usage:
//indent ./a.c;gcc -O0 ./a.c
//./a.out max r/w repeat timeout

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  time_t const start_time = time (NULL);
  time_t timeout;
  int max;
  int repeat;
  if (argc == 5)
    {
      max = atoi (argv[1]);
      repeat = atoi (argv[3]);
      timeout = ((time_t) (atoi (argv[4])));
    }
  else
    return 1;

  unsigned char **block_array =
    calloc (sizeof (unsigned char *), (size_t) (max));

  size_t block_length = (size_t) (1024u * 1024u);

  unsigned char data[3];
  data[0] = 'a';
  data[1] = 'b';
  data[2] = 'c';

  unsigned i = 0u;
  //initialize block_array
  for (i = 0u; i < max; i++)
    {
      do
    {
      if ((timeout > ((time_t) (0)))
          && ((time (NULL) - start_time) > timeout))
        {
          puts ("timeouted!");
          return 0;
        }
      block_array[i] = malloc (block_length);
      if (block_array[i] != NULL)
        {
          unsigned bi = 0u;
          for (bi = 0u; bi < block_length; bi++)
        block_array[i][bi] = data[bi % ((unsigned) (sizeof (data)))];
        }
      else
        {
          printf ("%u error\n", i);
        }
    }
      while (NULL == block_array[i]);
    }
  puts ("init ok");

  unsigned score = 0u;
//do page read test
  if ('r' == argv[2][0])
    for (;;)
      {
    for (i = 0u; i < max; i++)
      {
        if ((timeout > ((time_t) (0)))
        && ((time (NULL) - start_time) > timeout))
          {
        puts ("timeouted!");
        goto show_score;
          }

        unsigned bi = 0u;
        for (bi = 0u; bi < block_length; bi++)
          {
        data[bi % ((unsigned) (sizeof (data)))] = block_array[i][bi];
          }
        score++;
      }
    if (repeat >= 0)
      {
        repeat--;
        if (0 == repeat)
          goto show_score;
      }
      }
//do page write test
  else if ('w' == argv[2][0])
    for (;;)
      {
    for (i = 0u; i < max; i++)
      {
        if ((timeout > ((time_t) (0)))
        && ((time (NULL) - start_time) > timeout))
          {
        puts ("timeouted!");
        goto show_score;
          }

        unsigned bi = 0u;
        for (bi = 0u; bi < block_length; bi++)
          {
        block_array[i][bi] = data[bi % ((unsigned) (sizeof (data)))];
          }
        score++;
      }
    if (repeat >= 0)
      {
        repeat--;
        if (0 == repeat)
          goto show_score;
      }
      }
show_score:
  printf ("score:%u\n", score);
  return 0;
}
```

I also same test Debian Jessie(Linux 3.16)(lesser test) and Debian Stretch(Linux 4.9)(more test to sure)

I already repeat many times same test to sure this,so I only post a short result.

Test result:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo |grep SwapTotal
SwapTotal:             0 kB
$ time ./a.out 100 r  5 -1
init ok
score:500

real    0m2.689s
user    0m2.604s
sys 0m0.080s
$ time ./a.out 100 w  5 -1
init ok
score:500

real    0m2.567s
user    0m2.496s
sys 0m0.060s
$
```

Comment: This is a coding question and belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main assignment inside the loop in both the 'r' and 'w' cases reads from memory and writes back to memory i.e. they are essentially the same - you aren't really testing memory read versus memory write. This is borne out by the fact that the times in each case are pretty close.

The 'w' case may be slightly faster because the cache probably contains the value you want to read from memory, since you aren't changing the source address in that case.

Comment: `aren't changing the source address in that case.('w')`? I can't understand how I'm changing address because seem I make a symmetrical case.

Comment: the address where you are "reading" from is NOT changing therefore after the first "read" from memory the contents of that location will likely be found in the cache and not loaded from memory at all. this may explain the slightly faster execution of the 'w' case.

Comment: Are you mean `a=b`,that speed of `b` is more important than `a`?

Comment: No (not sure what you mean) ... I'm saying that in the 'w' case, since the value you are using on the right hand side of the assignment is the same in each iteration of the loop, the CPU does not need to fetch it from memory each time - it will fetch it from the cache instead which is much faster. in the 'r' case, the right hand side is different each time so the value won't be in the cache, it will have to read from memory each time. the bottom line though is that each case is essentially the same - i was just trying to explain the slightly faster 'w' case which was the gist of your question.

Comment: AFAIK,`left=right`in 'w' case ,`right` is ***cache hit*** and `left` is ***cache miss***;in 'r' case `right` is ***cache miss*** and `left` is ***cache hit*** (I think that small `data` array near always in cache,because it is enough small and is enough "hot"). why in 'w' case is more ***cache hit***?

Comment: I don't think cache hit/miss applies for writes to memory ... only reads from memory, so it simplifies to in the 'w' case the memory read will mostly be a cache hit whereas in the 'r' case the memory read will mostly be a cache miss.